Is this sentence correct? - "es sich merken kann"
I'm studying some German sentences, and I came upon this one

Tom hat so viele Freunde, dass es sich nicht alle Namen merken kann.

With this translation given

Tom has so many friends that he can't remember all their names.

I don't understand why it's "es sich" and not "er sich".
Is it simply a typo?
The only way I see how it could be correct with "es" is if it's meant in the sense that Tom's gender is unknown to the speaker or if Tom is a nonbinary person - kind of like the English "they", although I don't know if "es" is used like that in German.

Provided that the subject of the subclause is meant to be Tom, this is definitely a typo for "er". It doesn't really make sense for anything else to be the subject, so I can say with confidence that you came across a typo.

There might be some context where "es" is Tom's mobile phone, or something like that.

@PaŭloEbermann: Ein Mobiltelefon kann sich nicht alle Freunde merken?

@userunknown yes (the older ones had a somewhat limited capacity, and here it might be even a hyperbole).

Für einen Eintrag mit Name und Nummer benötigt man im Schnitt ca. 50 Bytes, d.h. in ein Megabyte passen 20.000 Kontakte. Wie viel MB hatten denn die alten Händies? Aber gut - ich war kein Early-Adopter damals; mag sein. Ich hatte mal eins in der Hand, da ging der Kalender nur bis 2007 oder 2013 o.s.ä. - und war noch in Benutzung. Ist jedenfalls vorstellbar, selbst wenn es real nicht vorgekommen sein mag, so kann man ja sprachlich auch phantastische Sachverhalte darstellen. Du hast Recht.

That depends on the context, which unfortunately was not provided in the question. So your question cannot be answered because you did not provide enough information. (Btw: The same problem would arise if the sentence was in English. Also in English you need the context to tell whether the pronouns gender is correct or wrong.)
In principle, in German each personal pronoun must always agree with the gender of the noun to which it refers. The question is therefore: to which noun does the pronoun refer?
(In German, there are many different types of pronoun. When this answer refers to a "pronoun", it always means a personal pronoun.)
Option 1: The pronoun refers to a noun that appears in the same sentence.
The noun usually comes before the pronoun, but it can also come after it. The order noun-pronoun is much more common than the reverse order.

Sebastian hat 14 Freunde und Sandra hat sogar nur 8 Freunde. Beide haben so wenige Freunde, dass sie sich die Namen ihrer Freunde sehr gut merken können. Aber Tom hat mehr als 700 Freunde. Tom hat so viele Freunde, dass er sich nicht alle Namen merken kann.
Sebastian has 14 friends and Sandra has only 8 friends. Both have so few friends that they can remember their friends' names very well. But Tom has more than 700 friends. Tom has so many friends that he can't remember all their names.

This example is about how many names individual people can remember. The pronoun therefore refers to the masculine noun "Tom", which is the name of a male person, so the pronoun must also be masculine ("er").
Option 2: The pronoun refers to a noun in a different sentence.
(Here, too, the pronoun usually refers to a noun in a previous sentence. The other order is also possible, but rarely used.)

Tom hat sein neues Handy verloren, und als Ersatz hat ihm sein Vater ein Handy aus den 1990er-Jahren gegeben. Aber dieses alte Handy hat nur sehr wenig Speicherplatz. Tom hat versucht, die Telefonnummer all seiner Freunde einzugeben, aber der Speicherplatz dieses alten Handys reicht nicht aus. Tom hat so viele Freunde, dass es sich nicht alle Namen merken kann.
Tom lost his new cell phone, so his father gave him a cell phone from the 1990s as a replacement. But this old cell phone has very little storage space. Tom tried to enter the phone numbers of all his friends, but the storage space of this old cell phone is not enough. Tom has so many friends that it can't remember all their names.

This example is about the ability of an electronic device to remember personal data. The pronoun refers to the neuter noun "Handy" in this example, so the pronoun must also be neuter ("es").
Option 3: The pronoun refers to a noun that does not exist in the text, but only in the minds of the conversation partners, which is also part of the context.
A dialog:
Walter shows Bernhard an old photo. In the photo, Walter is holding a glass of wine and is sitting with a very old white-haired woman. On the table is a birthday cake with the number 90 written on it in icing. Sitting next to them is a second man who looks a lot like Walter. Walter points to the second man and says,

Das ist mein Bruder, er heißt Tom.
This is my brother, his name is Tom.

Then he points to the woman in the photo and says,

Leider wird ihre Demenz immer schlimmer, und Tom ärgert sich manchmal sehr darüber, dass sie die Namen seiner Freunde vergisst. Tom hat so viele Freunde, dass sie sich nicht alle Namen merken kann.
Unfortunately, her dementia is getting worse and worse, and Tom is sometimes very annoyed that she forgets the names of his friends. Tom has so many friends that she can't remember all their names.

In this example, the point is that the old woman, who is presumably Walter and Tom's mother, forgets the names of her son's friends. Therefore, the pronoun in this example refers to the feminine noun "Mutter" or to the old woman's name which must be a feminine noun, because the named person is female. But in all the words that Walter speaks, there is no mention of the woman's name, nor of the noun "Mutter" or any other noun that could refer to this woman. In the entire example, there is no other feminine noun to which the pronoun could refer. The pronoun "sie" therefore refers to a noun that does not appear anywhere in the spoken text, but only in the minds of Walter and Bernhard. But that is enough. The pronoun must also agree in this case with the grammatical gender of this virtual noun.

The pronoun "es" is never used like the English "they" for persons with unknown gender. German pronouns to NOT match with the biological gender of a person!. German pronouns match with the grammatical gender of a noun! This noun can identify a person (like a name or like words like "Mutter", "Lehrer", "Nachbar", ...) but it can also be any other noun ("Handy", "Tisch", "Neugier", ...). So, in German personal pronouns do NOT refer to persons! They refer to nouns!
In German you can (and must) use the pronoun "es" only if the noun that identifies a person is a neuter noun, independent of the persons biological gender:

unknown biological gender


Das Kind hat den ganzen Tag gespielt, jetzt ist es müde.
Das Baby schläft. Es wird bald wieder aufwachen.


neuter noun and pronoun for a female person


Das Mädchen trinkt Milch. Es hat langes, blondes Haar.
Das Weib hat mich betrogen. Ich will es nicht mehr sehen.


neuter noun and pronoun for a male person (Albert Einstein)


Das Genie ist leider schon tot. Es hat die spezielle und die allgemeine Relativitätstheorie formuliert.

If a person's biological sex is known, there has been an exception for about 50 years: in this case, it is permitted for the pronoun to also match the biological sexus. But the matching with the grammatical gender is always correct too.
If you want to refer to a single person with unknown gender in German, you use er/sie in a written text and er oder sie when you speak:

Die Person trug einen schwarzen Mantel mit Kapuze und rannte aus dem Geschäft. Er/sie war ungefähr 170 bis 180 cm groß und steig in ein wartendes Auto, das dann mit hoher Geschwindigkeit davon fuhr.
The person was wearing a black coat with a hood and ran out of the store. They was about 170 to 180 cm tall and got into a waiting car, which then drove away at high speed.


This is plain wrong: you do not use "er/sie", you use SIE, because it is "DIE Person". For the same reason you use "es" if talking about children of either sex, because it is "DAS Kind". German words consist of letters and slashes are not letters at all. (asterisks, for that matter, aren't either)

@bakunin: "Er/sie" was wrong, if the pronoun would refer to the feminine noun "die Person". But it's correct if the pronoun refers to an unspoken (or unwritten) noun in the mind of the author to express that the fleeing person has a gender that is unknown to the author.
